# Motional Emf confusion

Tags: voltage, electromagnetism, induction, emf

I know that in motional emf V=Blv where B,l,and v are perpendicular to each other. When one of them isn't, then there would be no emf. What formula supports this?(mathematical evidence)
Can anyone help?

Comment: *When one of them isn't, then there would be no emf* - that is largely untrue.

Comment: yeah I get you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> I know that in motional emf V=Blv where B,l,and v are perpendicular to each other. When one of them isn't, then there would be no emf. What formula supports this?(mathematical evidence) Can anyone help?

No mathematical formula supports that other mathematical formula. There is no mathematical 'evidence'.

The mathematical formula is a description of the real world. When we do the experiment, we see what happens, and we put together a formula to describe it. It's physical evidence, not mathematical evidence.

Often what happens is one group puts together one formula, another group suggests a different formula, and each tries to reproduce the others' work, along with a few third groups attempting to reproduce their work. Some formulae will be found not to describe what happens, and these will be discarded. Some will pass every test that's been thrown at them, and these will eventually become 'Laws'. This is call the Scientific Method. Sometimes, even after a law has been well established, it will fail in some new set of circumstances, and be superseded by a new more comprehensive law, like for instance Newton's Gravitation being superseded by Einstein's General Relativity.

Comment: I didn't know that there's no formula to support that,. Thank you so much for clarifying!

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are asking about is the mathematical vector expression that both your scalar expression and Fleming's Left Hand Rule comes from:

This would be the equation for the Lorentz Force. Of course you could also just say Maxwell's equations.

Basically ripped off Wikipedia:

\$ \overline{F} = q\overline{E}+q\overline{v} \times \overline{B}\$

\$ \overline{F} = \overline{I}\ell \times \overline{B} \$

The 
\$ q\overline{v} \times \overline{B}\$ term is the motional EMF that you are interested in.

The \$q\overline{E}\$ is just for the force exerted on an an electrons moving parallel to the component of an electric field.

> When one of them isn't, then there would be no emf

This is wrong. You just stated that if they are not perpindicular then the force is zero. I'm sure this isn't what you have in your mind but this is what you said.

What it is saying is that the mutually perpendicular components of all three terms determine each other. Not that they are zero if the vectors are not all perpendicular to one another.

Comment: Maybe it's just me but for \$q\overline{E}\$, shouldn't the electron be moving against the electric field? Where's the negative sign?

Comment: Oh wait. The negative sign is part of the electron's charge. Duuurrrr.

Comment: Thank you so much! Grateful for your answer.

Comment: And yeah the negative sign is the electron's charge. haha

Comment: @DKNguyen the Lorentz force formula is not one of Maxwell's equations. It was derived properly 30 years later. Maxwell's equations contain only fields and charge. Motion was introduced later. One can claim that Maxwell's equations contain Lorentz force law because they actually contain special relativity which leads to the Lorentz force formula. The elementary school physics often try to derive either Induction from Lorentz force or vice versa, but that's not a valid proof, it shows only the laws are compatible.

Comment: @user287001 I did not realize the two were so far removed from each other (even considering how Maxwell's Equations are so simple that you need to derive everything from them to be of practical use)

Comment: Maxwell's equations is a compilation of preceding works from such as Gauss, Ampere and Faraday. Only the formula for the rotor of the magnetic field as the time derivative of the electric field is Maxwell's own. It's not based on measurements. He inserted it without standing up behind his desk only to prevent other mathematicians to spoil his work. Without that equation the rest of the equations contain an easy to see (for mathematicians) contradiction.